# ZeroMQ Topic Filtering with Pub/Sub (Java binding)

Tags: filtering, publish-subscribe, zeromq

How can I get ZeroMQ to support topics and pattern matching?

e.g.

```
stocks.*
stocks.appl
```

From my understanding ZeroMQ..the topic will be part of the message so I need someway of separating the topic from the actual message in the subscriber.
Whats the best way of separating the topic and message? Do you need a special character (e.g. SOH)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Need to use a pub/sub envelope

[Pub-Sub Message Envelopes](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#Pub-Sub-Message-Envelopes)

Comment: Did you find anything on pattern matching?

Answer (score 4):

Quoting [http://zeromq.org/area:faq](http://zeromq.org/area%3afaq):

> Can I subscribe to messages using regex or wildcards?
>
> > No. Prefix matching only.